# Categorical variables with too many levels in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a machine learning problem where the dependent variable is binomial (Yes/No) and some of the independent variables are categorical (with more than 100 levels). I'm not sure whether dummy coding these categorical variables and then passing them to the machine learning model is a optimal solution.

Is there a way to deal with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: These type of questions, which do not involve programming, does not belong to StackOverflow. Search about it on internet or post to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: We can ask questions, right?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to create dummy variables on the categorical variables. Before that, try to combine some of the categorical variables.